# Why there could be only one create statement in one batch in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What's the reasoning behind this design decision?

Comment: That is how SQL Server is defined.  If you have questions about language design, then Microsoft can (perhaps) answer them.  The real reason is because Sybase did it that way, and SQL Server is based on the Sybase code base. My guess is that Sybase was concerned about scoping issues, to ensure that created objects are available for subsequent declarations.  But that is just a guess.

Comment: It doesn't matter - the rules exist and you must live within them. Off-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you would have to designers of Sysbase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why there could be only one create statement in one batch in T-SQL?

The limitations about which statements can be combined in a batch, and which statements must be the first statement in a batch are technical limitations of the TSQL parser.  There's no "good" reason for them; as the language evolved over the many versions balancing introducing new syntax while maintaining backwards compatibility introduced some quirks in the language like this.  The requirement to terminate the statement before a CTE with ';' is another similar quirk.

The typical workaround for this is to push the DDL statement into a nested batch. EG:

```
declare @sql1 nvarchar(max) = '
create schema foo;
'
declare @sql2 nvarchar(max) = '
create table foo.bar(id int);
'

exec (@sql1)
exec (@sql2)
```